# I am trying to implement Push Notification using "node-gcm" package in Meteor.js

Tags: node.js, meteor, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

When i run the server and click in "Send". In server it is showing sending "success" but i am not getting any notification in my android-device.
Console I am getting as follows:

```
Sending Successfully...
{ multicast_id: 6701351013026462000,
success: 1,
failure: 0,
canonical_ids: 0,
results: [ { message_id: '0:1425279536646035%a80ac63e002efde3' } ] }
```

server/app.js:

```
if(Meteor.isServer){
    var gcm = Meteor.npmRequire('node-gcm');

    var message = new gcm.Message({
        collapseKey: 'demo',
        delayWhileIdle: true,
        timeToLive: 3
    });

    //create sender with My Project API Key
    var sender = new gcm.Sender('AIzaSyCTrkiGnZBXwfGIJDzwcwWBZoImd5DRw');

    var registrationIds = [];

    // As of now manually i am giving my device registrationID 
    registrationIds.push('APA91bH9JCWmstRQ93FmZw6NlitI5-4kG1DPXHwrpIy0k8zWUlK2Ono0_8ULC2vOiFRkRgkY0s1IcatXU2jes0fwvuwxjBULX9HUmClDCkbqHtp0fwSh4I9igEC0CfglbEXmjpFI_ckp275adYZB16lAbR75bk6L2xf-OmsmoDig-gNaW88');
}

Meteor.methods({
     'notify': function(title, msg) {

      message.addData('title',title);
      message.addData('message',msg);

      sender.send(message, registrationIds, 10, function (err, result) {
            if(err){
                console.error(err);
            }
            else {
                console.log("Sending Successfully...");
                console.log(result);
            }
       });
    }
});
```

client/app.js:

```
Template.form.events({
    'click [data-action="send-notification"], submit': function (event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Meteor.call('notify', template.$('[data-field="title"]').val(), template.$('[data-field="message"]').val(), function(err, res) {
        console.log("I am from Client Event...");
        console.log(res);
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            if (res.userCount) {
                alert('Notification sent.');
            }
        }
    });
   }
});
```

## client/app.html

```
<head>
  <title>My App</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{> loginButtons}}
    {{#if showForm}}
        {{> form}}
    {{/if}}
</body>

<template name="form">

    <form>
        <input type="text" data-field="title" placeholder="Title">
        <input type="text" data-field="message" placeholder="Message">
        <button data-action="send-notification">Send</button>
    </form>

</template>
```

Comment: couple suggestions would be check all requirements in the [**doc**](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) and if it's client side error, make sure you have the correct permissions, your data or wifi's working and etc. [**client doc**](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html). Sometimes a missing permission could cause failure for the client device. Try on different devices to see if it's device compatibility issue? Hope this gives you some idea

Comment: I know the question is old, but for people who googled this, you are setting a timeToLive of 3 and also delayWhileIdle: true so if the device is idle, you will not get the notification